# Implement a generic class which has a constraint which needs a generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have following code:

```
 public class Generic1<T, T2> where T : Generic2<T2>
    where T2 : new()
{

}


public class Generic2<T> where T : new()
{
    public T GetT()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

which makes it possible to do:

`var g = new Generic1<Generic2<int>, int>();`

But what I really want is to use it like (but keep the constraint that it must be of type Generic2):

`var g = new Generic1<Generic2<int>();`

Since T2 is already clear why do I have to specify it separately?
I can't do:

`var g = new Generic1<Generic2<int>, double>();`

So is there a way to change Generic1 or Generic2 to acchieve that?
Like:

```
public class Generic1<T> where T : Generic2<T2>
{

}
```

But this doesn't compile :(

**Edit I**

Maybe I asked wrong. It's a very stripped-down example. I need T to be of type Generic2

Comment: You can make your method inside the Generic2 generic rather than the class itself

Comment: I was going to say, get rid of `T2` if you don't need it.

Comment: @Codexer: You're close, but if you think about it really hard, it's `T` that's unnecessary, not `T2`. `T` can just be replaced by `Generic2<T2>`.

Comment: @Heinzi correct, it's Monday, can I use that as an excuse :)

Answer (score 2):

If `T` is always `Generic2<T2>`, then you don't need `T` and can just get rid of it. You just need to replace every occurrence of `T` in Generic1 with `Generic2<T2>`.

Example: If Generic1 currently looks like this:

```
public class Generic1<T, T2> where T : Generic2<T2> where T2 : new()
{
   public T DoSomething() { ... }
   public T2 DoSomethingElse() { ... }
}
```

you can replace it with:

```
public class Generic1<T2> where T2 : new()
{
   public Generic2<T2> DoSomething() { ... }
   public T2 DoSomethingElse() { ... }
}
```

Generic1 can now be simply instantiated as:

```
var g = new Generic1<int>();
```

(Obviously, you can rename `T2` to `T` afterwards.)